# How do movement-based theories account for extraposition?

Tags: syntax, movement, transformational-grammar, discontinous-constituents

I'm looking at this example of [Extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuity_(linguistics)#Extraposition) from Wikipedia:

[image]

Then under [Theoretical Accounts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuity_(linguistics)#Theoretical_accounts) (of discontinuity in general) it is written that "[m]odern theories of transformational grammar ... assume a movement or copying procedure".

It is my understanding that:

- The subject is never dominated by the VP node.
- Nodes can move up the tree but not down.

If this is correct, how can movement account for this kind of extraposition? As I see it, either the subject *something to take seriously* has to start under the VP node and its head has to move up (is it even possible that only the head moves?), or the CP *to take seriously* of the subject has to move down the tree. Either way one of these constraints is violated.

So how do "modern theories" account for this kind of extraposition?

Comment: mark baltin has a good review article on the analysis of extraposition in generative grammar. if you can get access to that article it would probably be helpful: Baltin, M. (2017). Extraposition. The Wiley Blackwell Companion to Syntax, Second Edition, 1-33.

Comment: That's not extraposition, but postposing. Most extraposition constructions have the dummy subject "it" and  a postverbal subordinate clause, e.g. "It is fortunate that you could come".

Comment: @BillJ this type of thing is also called extraposition, as least in generative grammar. for instance ross's dissertation calls this extraposition

Comment: @BillJ There are two phenomena that are denoted with _extraposition_, the one in the question and so-called "it-exptraposition", which is what you are pointing to. The two phenomena are related, but also distinct to an extent.

Comment: The answer to the question is at least in part present in the Wikipedia article on extraposition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics).

Comment: @TimOsborne do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition#Theoretical_analyses? The movement there seems to be downward. I learned that movement is *always* upward, but it was in a crash course - is that not correct, or am I mistaken that this is downward?

Comment: @one-off-post thanks for the reference. I have access to that article, I will have a close look!

Comment: This particular example (and its accompanying diagram) are not representative of what is called _Extraposition_ in generative grammar, regardless of what Wikipedia may say. And calling something "movement-based" is not a good label, either. It's the principle of derivations with the syntactic cycle that's involved. If you think something is "movement", then what's moving, and where did it move from, and what else might move? There's a vast difference between theories like McCawley's and theories that treat every sentence as if it were unrelated to every other one.

Comment: A much better definition, [with sources, is available here](https://www.thoughtco.com/extraposition-grammar-term-1690626).

Comment: @jlawler op's phenomenon has been referred to as extraposition in generative grammar at least since ross 1967

Comment: In Ross's most recent [list of transformation rules](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf), there are 4 different rules with names involving _extraposition_: Extraposition (with dummy _It_), Extraposition from NP, Extraposition of PP, Extraposition of PP from AP (_How sure of this are you? ~ How sure are you of this?_). OP's example is Extraposition from NP. They're all cyclic.

Comment: @jlawler i see, i agree that the given trees are not representative of how the phenomenon would normally be analyzed. i'm just pointing out that the descriptive phenomenon is indeed referred to as extraposition.

Comment: @Keelan you are right, the movement shown on wikipedia is downward. the relative clause should be adjoined to S (cyclically, as jlawler points out), not to VP. some evidence for this is given in baltin's article.

Comment: The "upward movement" meme comes from the principle of the cycle. Cyclic transformations like passive and extraposition happen (if at all) on the bottom cycle first, and then again on the next cycle up, and so on until the main clause is reached. That's why you can have passive subordinate clauses in a sentence with a passive matrix verb; passive has applied several times. That's the "temporal" metaphor that leads to metaphoric "movement"; it's just a way to relate sentence variants.

Comment: @Keelan I have corrected the Wikipedia trees in the article on extraposition. Have a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition#Theoretical_analyses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to my teacher, and apparently this is more advanced than what I should be trying to do right now. However, he explained that there are broadly two ways to deal with this:

- Accept that only part of the node moves up, and leaves a copy for the remainder to connect to.
- Allow downward movement of the verb.